# website is not displaying full length on iphone

Tags: css, background-image

I have a website that shows correctly on my computer but on a iphone it seems to cut off at a certain stop:

http://yesiamshow.biz

can anyone tell me why this happens. I tried to adjust my CSS but it always seems to cut off. I know I have an image as a background repeating but it should be the full length of the mobile iphone screen, right?

Comment: Looks good to me on my iPhone, except being cut of at the right, but the length seems fine and the background is being displayed

Comment: So not the length, the width is being cutoff

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setting min-width: 1110px; for body should work.